# Opening Spotify and other applications using python

Tags: python

I've been trying to look for some code that can open downloaded applications. I'm not sure if it adds to the problem, but I have 2 drivers. One D drive with my downloads and one C drive with my bootups.

P.S
Regarding Spotify, I don't mean playing songs from python. Simply opening up the application.
Thanks!

Comment: Simply opening an application? I think that there are far better solutions if it's just opening like creating a .bat script on windows or some bash in Linux instead of Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you know where the file path of your downloaded applications are, then you can open using `webbrowser` and `os.startfile` -

**webbrowser**-

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new('path of file')
```

**os.startfile**-

```
import os
os.startfile('path of file')
```